# Visual Studio with Ionic 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I installed visual studio 2015 with the right plugins (Cordova, Ionic templates..).
When I create an Ionic project, and after building, the solution explorer shows only the Dependencies of the project.

What I have missed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I deleted this folder, reopen the solution and everything is OK:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache